# Javascript - Placeholder after text

Tags: javascript, html, css

On googles calculator when you click on square root or sin, it shows a "placeholder" parenthese that disappears as soon as end the parentheses. Is there a simple built-in method in HTML?

[image: Googles Calculator]

Comment: You don't have to write code. But in words how would you do it?

Comment: See [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place HTML elements in the `input`s value, but you could make it look like you are.

Google fakes an `input` tag instead of putting a real one, so whenever you type when focused on it, they append the text you typed, and after it puts on a parenthesis if needed so it looks better. They have a span in which goes all the text and right after it goes the parenthesis.

We can take advantage of the `contenteditable` attribute in order to create a fake input from another element, and then add fake parenthesis as needed in the `:after` pseudo element:

*(The logic behind the parenthesis inserting is still very simple as it is not the main point.)*

```js
let fakeInput = document.getElementById("fakeinput");

fakeInput.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
  if(e.key == "(") {
    fakeInput.setAttribute("parenses", ")".repeat((fakeInput.getAttribute("parenses")||"").length+1));
  } else if (e.key == ")") {
    fakeInput.setAttribute("parenses", ")".repeat(Math.max((fakeInput.getAttribute("parenses")||"").length-1, 0)));
  }
});
```

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: box-shadow 0.25s linear;
}

#fakeinput:after {
  content: attr(parenses);
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div parenses="" id="fakeinput" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Notice the use of the `attr` and the `parenses` attribute in our CSS to modify the contents of the `:after` pseudo element, as we can't modify pseudo elements in JS.

We could wrap the fake input in a parent that would contain the fake input and a span that would contain the parenthesis, apply the styles to the parent, and when the parent is clicked we'd focus the fake input and apply the parenthesis to the span instead of having an attribute that contains the parenthesis which might be cleaner.

---

An alternative solution is having an element that floats right, with the value of a `)` when needed, and if a closing parenthesis is typed you'd just remove the element. The following is just a very basic example that could be improved, but it shows the general idea:

```js
let parens = document.getElementById("parenthesis");
document.getElementById("inputtext").addEventListener("keypress", e => {
    //More sophisticated code to check for unclosed parenthesises instead of this one:
    if(e.key == "(") {
        parens.classList.add("visible");
    } else if (e.key == ")") {
        parens.classList.remove("visible");
    }
});
```

```css
html {
   box-sizing:border-box;
}

*, *:after, *:before {box-sizing: inherit;}

#parenthesis
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color:gray;
    display: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#parenthesis.visible {
    display: block;
}

input
{
    border:0;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input:focus
{
    outline-width:0;
}

.inputholder
{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputholder">
    <span id="parenthesis">)</span>
    <input type="text" id="inputtext"/>
</div>
```